# Is there a stringr equivalent for grep with value = TRUE?

Tags: r, stringr

Is there a `stringr` equivalent for `grep` with `value` set to `TRUE`? (I would like to avoid the `NA`s returned by the `stringr` command below.)

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("a", "b", "a")
grep("a", x, value = TRUE)  # returns "a" "a"
str_extract(x, "a")  # returns "a" NA  "a"
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `str_subset`:

```
str_subset(x,"a")
[1] "a" "a"
```

The helpfile states the equivalence:

> str_subset() is a wrapper around x[str_detect(x, pattern)], and is
>   equivalent to grep(pattern, x, value = TRUE).